# What is the recommended way to develop docker containers for Linux on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, volume, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### Background

I am developing a Spring Boot application that will be deployed on Linux Redhat.
As this is a Java application, I can develop on Windows 10 and this is my preference.
To simplify deployment, I have dockerized the application.

### Objectives

1. I would like to test the container on my Windows 10 development computer:

   - Without installing a VM
   - Without using Hyper V as a VM.
   - Without WSL 2.0 (WSL 1.0 can be used)
2. I need to create a volume so that data written by the container can be accessed on the Windows host during and after the container runs.
3. The scripts I write to load and run the docker should be as similar as possible as those I will use to deploy on the target Linux Redhat server.

### What I have tried

I have installed Docker for Windows on my Windows PC and followed the documentation to allow me to run docker in WSL 1.0.

There are a number of tweaks that need to be done to make this work, and I am still not able to configure a volume to meet my requirement.

Curiously, I happened to try to run the container using docker on from a Windows command prompt and it seems to run too. (though volumes still do not work here either).

This surprised me because I thought that a Linux image can only be loaded into a Linux OS as docker does not run the container in a VM.

### My questions

1. Can I indeed test my Linux container using the Windows prompt or may I run into issues down the road? (issues meaning differences in deployment and run time behavior compared to deployment and running on the Linux target machine).
2. If a Linux container can run from the Windows prompt, do I even need WSL to run the docker on my windows PC?
3. What are the advantages, if any, of using WSL to test and test the container in development considering the fact that docker on WSL 1.0 seems to require a little work to get running "flawlessly" on Windows?

Comment: Are you also using Docker on the target system?  If you're not, then a VM seems like a much more natural fit (you'd be able to run the _exact_ application and deployment scripts without repackaging things for Docker).

Comment: Yes. I am using Docker on the target system. But my requirements are not to use a VM. They take up a lot of space on my development machine, they take time to install. 
There are two options I am considering:
1. Testing the Linux container in WSL 1.0
2. Testing the Linux container in the Windows command prompt